# My sand box solution simply does nothing (item added) on my site?

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution

I have a sand box code which iterates through items after they are added. It works perfectly fine on one website I have on a VM, and the site is literally set up in the exact same way. But the sand box code which works on the VM does not work on my production server. If all I have in my code is to add an item to an existing list, it won't even do that.

The resource usage stays at 0.00 all day long which makes me think it's not even registering the "item added" event.

What are key causes to look for when things like this happen? All the references, elements file, and column names are the same on both sites and in both codes (as the code is copy pasted).

Note: There's actually other functional solutions in the same site collection that are working fine.

Comment: First, check if your Feature is activated or not, the web-scoped feature are not auto-activated. Use debugger to see what's happening with the event receiver.

Comment: In our environment, I cannot debug in the development environment. That is why we usually do our development on our own servers and then just upload the wsp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aveenav's answer was the key. I mistook his "Activate feature" as telling me to activate the solution, but activating the site feature fixed everything.